# Difference between Information Gain and Mutual Information for feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, mutual-information

What is the difference between information gain and mutual information?

At this point, I understand that information gain is calculated between a random variable and target class for classification while mutual information is calculated between two random variables.

Does mutual information become the same as information when it is calculated between a random variable and target class?

Comment: information gain = mutual information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Relation_to_other_quantities

Answer (score 3):

**Information Gain (IG)** is the measure of entropy gained due to operations performed on an assigned dataset or random variable. Now, entropy here is just the variation in our dataset; so lesser the variation, lesser the entropy and in turn greater correlation among our dataset.

As you've hinted on a classification task, **Mutual Information (MI)** is a one-sided metric, whereas *information gain* is a two-sided metric. Actually both measure how relevant a feature is to a specific target class, & I've often observed various sources using the term *information gain* interchangeably with *mutual information*, as they are symmetric.

Important to note is while *mutual information* measures only the positive features, *information gain* measures both, negative as well as positive features of our data. For mathematical completeness, *information gain* of `X` given `Y` is given by `IG(X|Y) = H(x) - H(X|Y)`, and *mutual information* `I(X;Y)` is given by `I(X;Y) = sum_x sum_y P(X,Y) log {P(X,Y)/P(X)P(Y)}`.

Following links might help grasp better understanding of these terms:

- [Part-1 | Probability Distribution](https://medium.com/@neuralnets/probability-distribution-statistics-for-deep-learning-73a567e65dfa)
- [Part-2 | Information Theory](https://medium.com/machine-learning-bootcamp/demystifying-information-theory-e21f3af09455)

Hope it helps!